# Why am i getting a http client error in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I keep getting a error in a Blazor app while trying to navigate to it's login page. I think the error is coming from there. I've already installed the HTTP client packages in the program. As well as made a reference in Startup.

"There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'."

```
namespace GLI
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddTokenAuthenticationStateProvider();
       services.AddHttpClient();
       services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

    var secretkey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClsGlobal.Secret);
     //Configuring JWToken Authentication

    services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
      .AddJwtBearer(token =>
      {
    token.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    token.SaveToken = true;
    token.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretkey),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        //ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:45092/",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44358/",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
    }




@code {
RazorComponents.MaterialDesign.MdcDialog dialog;
LoginCredentials credentials = new LoginCredentials();
bool lastSigninFailed;

public Task SignIn()
  => dialog.ShowAsync();

public Task SignOut()
    => AuthStateProvider.SetTokenAsync(null);
async Task SubmitCredentials()
{
    var result = await Http.PostJsonAsync<LoginResult>("api/user/login", credentials);
    lastSigninFailed = result.Token == null;
    if (!lastSigninFailed)
    {
        // Success! Store token in underlying auth state service
        await AuthStateProvider.SetTokenAsync(result.Token);

        // Reset UI state
        await dialog.HideAsync();
        credentials = new LoginCredentials();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I guess you inject HttpClient into your class constructor?

Comment: Can you show your startup.cs file?

Comment: Hi R.Alfred, I know you're a new user and your question was voted to be closed and I don't want you to get too discouraged by StackOverflow.  Please take a look at this guide for asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Questions should be specific, and show short relevant code blocks if possible. I did my best to post a hopefully helpful answer anyways

Comment: The edit was helpful but note that you tagged `[blazor-clientside]` and that was wrong - you are using server-side. And that difference is essential here.

Comment: Yes, that was an error on my part. On server-side blazor, i should've been creating my own HttpClient instances as opposed to just using @inject HttpClient in my components. I was getting that error because there isn't one in DI and the inject HttpClient doesn't add one.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9941 - Article reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could show us your startup.cs file, but you could try adding this to your startup.cs to register the HttpClient service

```
if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
{
    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
    {
        var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
        return new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
        };
    });
}
```